# Python email regex doesn't work

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to get all email address from a text file using regular expression and Python but it always returns NoneType while it suppose to return the email. For example:

```
content = 'My email is lehai@gmail.com'
#Compare with suitable regex
emailRegex = re.compile(r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)')
mo = emailRegex.search(content)
print(mo.group())
```

I suspect the problem lies in the regex but could not figure out why.

Comment: Remove anchors: [`r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+'`](https://ideone.com/rxDrGq).

Comment: This is a terrible way to check email address. You might as well check for the presence of `@` only.

Comment: See also [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of spaces in `content`; remove the `^` and `$` to match anywhere:

`([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as a regex, but I am completely not sure whether it will work for you:

**([^@|\s]+@[^@]+.[^@|\s]+)**

Comment: `|` inside character class is a red flag - are you sure you want to exclude it from the character class?

Comment: @nhahtdh, As I told, I am not sure that it will work in all cases, it worked on me when I faced the same problem

Comment: `|` should not be used to say "alternation" in character class. `[@\s]` is already an alternation of 2 choices `@` or space character class. The extra `|` will add the literal `|` to the list of alternation.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I just checked again and it worked  on 'My email is lehai@gmail.com' perfectly, returning "lehai@gmail.com"

Comment: I'm not commenting about the correctness of your regex with respect to the question. I'm saying `|` should not be used as "alternation" in character class.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression doesn't match the pattern.

I normally call the regex search like this:

```
mo = re.search(regex, searchstring)
```

So in your case I would try

```
content = 'My email is lehai@gmail.com'
#Compare with suitable regex
emailRegex = re.compile(r'gmail')
mo = re.search(emailRegex, content)
print(mo.group())`
```

You can test your regex here: https://regex101.com/
This will work:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)
```